# how to convert .net framework 4.6.1 class library to .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-3.1

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{DE745HFD-4BE4-4C9A-BA8C-9148EA6793A0}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ABC.Core</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ABC.Core</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

which property add or update to convert my class library to a core 3.1 library

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, there is this community maintained tool you could use to upgrade your project(s) to the new csproj file format.

If you don't have a lot of customization (custom msbuild tasks added to your csproj file etc.) i've found it to work great!

https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017

I use this command:

`dotnet migrate-2019 migrate **\*.csproj --force --keep-assembly-info --no-backup`

[image]

Then simply change the targetframework(s) to `netcoreapp3.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `TargetFrameworkVersion` property with the following:

```
 <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

Have a look at the  [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) here